# Error when Parsing last position value from text file while streaming data in Julia

Tags: julia

I am streaming strings and parsing them into floats/ints from a .dat. Everything is going well until I work with the last item in the string, which returns an error.

Example Data:

```
x = "15505052|B|Other|2.22|250022|2776|09/2019|01/2004|"

y = split(x, "|")  # <-- one inner loop of the loop

if isblank(y[9]) == false
   floater = parse(Float64, y[9])
end
```

This is the error I receive:

```
ArgumentError("float64(String): invalid number format")
while loading In[42], in expression starting on line 56

 in float64 at string.jl:1613
 in parse at /Users/laptop/.julia/v0.3/Compat/src/Compat.jl:217
 in loan_aqsn at In[42]:36
```

I have visually inspected the last column in the above data strings and determined that the data should be parseable into a Float64, and indeed every other column works just fine.

What I have found is that I can individually parse lines from the .dat just fine (for testing purposes), but when I move to streaming the file Julia throws the error. The only thing I can figure out about this error is that it has to due with working with the final record in the string y[9], which makes no sense to me.

Any help with this frustrating problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing whether `y` is blank, when it is in fact an empty string:

```
x = "15505052|B|Other|2.22|250022|2776|09/2019|01/2004|"
y = split(x)
y[9]           # ""
isblank(y[9])  # false, since we have an empty string
float(y[9])    # ERROR: ArgumentError("float64(String): invalid number format")
```

You should modify your code to use `isempty()` instead

```
using Compat # for parse(Float, String)

if !isempty(y[9])
    floater = parse(Float64, y[9])
end
# do stuff
```

[Relevant manual section (for v0.3)](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/strings/?highlight=isblank#isblank)

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of isempty()

Answer (score 0):

Which julia version are you using? Mine doesn't recognize `parse(fmt,str)` as a valid command (v 0.3.10).

Try really parsing the numbers, not just converting them. That way the divisions are properly executed (like 01/2004 in the second `x`).

```
strs = ["12", "12.1", "12/3"]
for i in strs
    a::Float64 = eval(parse(i))
    println(a)
end
```

this works fine in my julia REPL, returning `12.0`,`12.1` and `4.0`.
Note that I am "executing" those numbers, opening a security concern if I use this code for other thing than a quick script.